# What is the meaning of the _YYOPTIM #define in lex/flex generated code?

Tags: c, linux, bison, flex-lexer

I am maintaining some very old flex (or maybe even lex) files that I believe were converted to .c at least 1.5 decades ago (and then checked into version control, so we still use them).

Within the generated .c file I can see a #define called prefix_YYOPTIM (where "prefix" is the usual application-specific prefix specified for all variables) which is #define'd to be 1; this then causes a block of code later in the parser to be enabled.

I have searched the web and in the flex documentation but cannot find any explanation of what this is supposed to do.  Is it to enable optimization?  Is anyone aware of documentation that explains what it does (the block of code that it enables is somewhat hard to comprehend)?

I ask because I believe there might be a bug in the block of code that it enables.  Unfortunately I cannot post any code here.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it enabled table compression in AT&T lex. What makes you think the code it produces is buggy?

Comment: Thanks -- very cool that you know that :-)   The code in that block, at least from the version of lex that was used to generate it (possibly very old) has casts from pointer to int, which don't play well on modern architectures.  However, I have since found this issue in other parts of the generated code (outside YYOPTIM block) and so I guess it is just a general issue, not to do with YYOPTIM, so my question is moot I guess.

Comment: i suppose you don't have the original lex file? Still, the scanner actions should be easy to extract from the generated scanner (there should be a massive switch where each case is a scanner action) and you might be able to figure out the patterns for each action without too much work.